# Testnet validator is not coming up the with leader schedule

Tags: solana, solana-cli, solana-program-library

Hello I have started the Testnet validator, and it's not validating at all, I have changed the Validator identity and Vote account identityy it's still showing the same info. There is no issue with catchup

Not sure what's happening here any Insight how to get my validator in the leader schedule would be appreciated

```bash
2022-08-03T06:24:06.016079779Z INFO  solana_core::replay_stage] Cyr4mmWDsH7spytcsG6oYf9SXaUqnWRxpabzdkXiUmvr reset PoH to tick 9206607040 (within slot 143853234). I am not in the leader schedule yet
[2022-08-03T06:24:06.593334562Z INFO  solana_core::replay_stage] Cyr4mmWDsH7spytcsG6oYf9SXaUqnWRxpabzdkXiUmvr reset PoH to tick 9206607104 (within slot 143853235). I am not in the leader schedule yet
[2022-08-03T06:24:06.948076736Z INFO  solana_core::replay_stage] Cyr4mmWDsH7spytcsG6oYf9SXaUqnWRxpabzdkXiUmvr reset PoH to tick 9206607168 (within slot 143853236). I am not in the leader schedule yet
[2022-08-03T06:24:07.424998113Z INFO  solana_core::replay_stage] Cyr4mmWDsH7spytcsG6oYf9SXaUqnWRxpabzdkXiUmvr reset PoH to tick 9206607296 (within slot 143853238). I am not in the leader schedule yet
[2022-08-03T06:24:07.956857415Z INFO  solana_core::replay_stage] Cyr4mmWDsH7spytcsG6oYf9SXaUqnWRxpabzdkXiUmvr reset PoH to tick 9206607360 (within slot 143853239). I am not in the leader schedule yet
[2022-08-03T06:24:08.880193502Z INFO  solana_core::replay_stage] Cyr4mmWDsH7spytcsG6oYf9SXaUqnWRxpabzdkXiUmvr reset PoH to tick 9206607424 (within slot 143853240). I am not in the leader schedule yet
[2022-08-03T06:24:10.297173162Z INFO  solana_core::replay_stage] Cyr4mmWDsH7spytcsG6oYf9SXaUqnWRxpabzdkXiUmvr reset PoH to tick 9206607488 (within slot 143853241). I am not in the leader schedule yet
[2022-08-03T06:24:10.419031603Z INFO  solana_core::replay_stage] Cyr4mmWDsH7spytcsG6oYf9SXaUqnWRxpabzdkXiUmvr reset PoH to tick 9206607552 (within slot 143853242). I am not in the leader schedule yet
[2022-08-03T06:24:10.565315799Z INFO  solana_core::replay_stage] Cyr4mmWDsH7spytcsG6oYf9SXaUqnWRxpabzdkXiUmvr reset PoH to tick 9206607616 (within slot 143853243). I am not in the leader schedule yet
[2022-08-03T06:24:11.082569598Z INFO  solana_core::replay_stage] Cyr4mmWDsH7spytcsG6oYf9SXaUqnWRxpabzdkXiUmvr reset PoH to tick 9206607936 (within slot 143853248). I am not in the leader schedule yet
```

Validator command

```
solana-validator --identity  /etc/solana-secrets/validator-keypair.json --vote-account /etc/solana-secrets/vote-account-keypair.json --known-validator 5D1fNXzvv5NjV1ysLjirC4WY92RNsVH18vjmcszZd8on --known-validator dDzy5SR3AXdYWVqbDEkVFdvSPCtS9ihF5kJkHCtXoFs --known-validator Ft5fbkqNa76vnsjYNwjDZUXoTWpP7VYm3mtsaQckQADN --known-validator eoKpUABi59aT4rR9HGS3LcMecfut9x7zJyodWWP43YQ --known-validator 9QxCLckBiJc783jnMvXZubK4wH86Eqqvashtrwvcsgkv --only-known-rpc --ledger /ledger --rpc-port 8899 --dynamic-port-range 8000-8020 --entrypoint entrypoint.testnet.solana.com:8001 --entrypoint entrypoint2.testnet.solana.com:8001 --entrypoint entrypoint3.testnet.solana.com:8001 --expected-genesis-hash 4uhcVJyU9pJkvQyS88uRDiswHXSCkY3zQawwpjk2NsNY --wal-recovery-mode skip_any_corrupted_record --limit-ledger-size
```

Validator version

```
root@solanatestnet0:~# solana-validator --version
solana-validator 1.11.1 (src:467c840d; feat:499180940)
root@solanatestnet0:~#
```

Answer (score 1):

It's normal to not be on the leader schedule, especially if you've just started your validator.  The leader schedule is determined by stake on the network, so highly staked nodes get a number of leader slots proportional to their stake.  If you get stake on your node, then you should see some leader slots.

Comment: if no stake is added any Idea how long usually it takes?

Comment: Unfortunately, you will never get leader slots without stake.